# Moving from a project GCP to a console GCP for a google workspace add-on

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace-add-ons

**General Problems**
So i've made a google slide add-on and it was originally uploaded with just the standard project GCP.  Know it's not possible to do that so I've made a new GCP project and i've started to move my previous project over to it.  But know i won't how to manage the store.

So i've developed this add-on
https://workspace.google.com/u/0/marketplace/app/math_equations/825973477142?pann=slides_addon_widget

Know how do i go about updating this because currently i can't upload from my new project because i can't put something on the store with the same name.

So my thoughts are i could either delete this project and re-upload it.  But i don't know the ramifications of that for the user using the older application.

Or i could upload it under a new name

not entirely sure this is the right place to post it, but this is where the google documents said to ask question to.

**How i got here**

So i made a google slide extension and i uploaded it to store.  The way i uploaded it is with a Google CLoud Platform Project that gets generated with any app scripts.

So a id of like project-id-5463578643545

Know it's been a few years since I've updated the application and know they require you to create a GCP that's not the default given with any app script project.

So i move the project over to id - Math-Equations-23~~~~~

So know i have the problem that my store listing is on the older project-id and not my current GCP project.

Comment: What's the issue with just updating the add-on that's already on the marketplace?

Comment: So i added to my description some key information.  But the big idea is that i had to move to a new GCP project.  So my store listing is on a different GCP.  So i'm wondering if i can migrate that @Ihopethisishelpfultoyou

Comment: So i found [this list](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project) with the comment

Comment: If your script is associated with an app listing on the Google Workspace Marketplace, your app listing, users, and reviews don't carry over to the Standard GCP project. You need to create a new app listing within the Standard GCP project and your users need to reinstall your app.

Comment: So this sounds like i need to just create a new listing and there's no migrating